# Google Guava Predicates.or() or Predicates.and() type

Tags: java, unit-testing, guava

In Guava, there is a utilities kind of method for Predicates class called 'or' or 'and', you can either pass a iterable or two predicates.

I have a code example like below:

```
class AccountNamePredicate implements Predicate<Account> {}
class AccountTypePredicate implements Predicate<Account> {}
class AccountManager {
    public Predicate<Account> getPredicate() {
         return Predicates.and(new AccountNamePredicate(), new AccountTypePredicate());
    }
}
```

My question is for the method getPredicate in AccountManager class, how can I test the method?

If I want to assert the return type of this method, how can I write the correct code. My assert statement below doesn't pass:

```
assertThat(getPredicate(), is(instanceOf(Predicate.class)));
```

Any idea about that?

Comment: the return type of a method guarantees that an instance of that return type will be retrieved unless it is null. so why do you explicitly need to test the return type of a method? the compiler does it for you.

Comment: @Juvanis Good point, I could skip the testing for return type. But Any idea about how to test this method? Do I need to test this? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to test? NEVER EVER EVER write unit tests unless they test something useful. (E.g. If you wrote `assertEqual(2, 1+1)` then you're wasting time and effort)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to test in your scenario. If you insist on test that you're testing the guava framework (guava development team already do that well) not your application.